# Free module is a right $R$-module with scaling operation.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, free-modules

Let $R$ be a ring and ruppose $F$ is a set of all functions from $S$ to $R$. Then, every element $u\in S$ can be viewed as a function from $S$ to $R$:
$$u(t)=\begin{cases}
1 \hbox{ if } t=u\\ 
0 \hbox{ if } t\neq u
\end{cases}$$
So $S$ is a subset of $F$.

Note that $F$ is an abelian group with $$[f+g](t):=f(t)+g(t)$$ for all $f,g\in F$, and $t\in S$.

I'm trying to prove that $F$ is a right $R$-module with scaling operation $$[f\cdot r](t):=f(t)r$$ for all $f\in F$, $r\in R$ and $t\in S$, but I'm having trouble how to show this.

Comment: hint: to show two functions $f,g\in F$ are equal, it suffices to show that $f(x)=g(x)$ for any $x\in S$.

Comment: in fact the fact you mention holds more generally; if $M$ is *any* (right) $R$-module, and $F=M^S$ is the set of all functions from $S$ to $M$, we can endow $F$ with a right $R$-module structure in exactly the same way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the required claim we have to check that for any $f,g\in F$, $r,s\in R$, and $t\in S$ we have

1)) $[(f+g)\cdot r](t)=([f\cdot r]+ [g\cdot r])(t)$

2)) $[f\cdot (r+s)](t)=([f\cdot r]+ [f\cdot s])(t)$.

For (1) we have

$[(f+g)\cdot r](t)=([f+g](t))r=(f(t)+g(t))r=f(t)r+g(t)r=[f\cdot r](t)+[g\cdot r](t)=([f\cdot r]+ [g\cdot r])(t)$

For (2) we have

$[f\cdot (r+s)](t)=f(t)(r+s)=f(t)r+f(t)s=[f\cdot r](t)+ [f\cdot s](t)=([f\cdot r]+ [f\cdot s])(t)$.

Comment: I'm trying to show that it has the scaling operation $$[f\cdot r](t):=f(t)r$$ It looks like to show (1) and (2), you have used the proposed operation instead of concluding that the operation holds. I may be wrong, but would you be able to explain a little more please?

Comment: @GregoireRocheteau Recall that we have to show that $F$ is a right $R$-module with the given scaling operation. That is the operation is already provided, but we have to check that it behaves accordingly to the axioms of a right $R$-module, what we did.